# browser object converting angularjs e2e test to protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Here is some code from an angularjs e2e test.

```
expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/phones');
```

Protractor gives this error.

> TypeError: Property 'browser' of object # is not a function

In particular, how can I change the line to fix the protractor error? 
In general, where can I find docs on the webdriverjs browser object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
//using full URL
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://host:port/your/url/phones');

//or using baseUrl
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + '/phones');
```

You can find the [API here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md).

And this is what I got when using `console.log(browser);`:

```
{ controlFlow: [Function],
  schedule: [Function],
  getSession: [Function],
  getCapabilities: [Function],
  getCapability: [Function],
  quit: [Function],
  actions: [Function],
  executeScript: [Function],
  executeAsyncScript: [Function],
  call: [Function],
  wait: [Function],
  sleep: [Function],
  getWindowHandle: [Function],
  getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
  getPageSource: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  getCurrentUrl: [Function],
  getTitle: [Function],
  findDomElement_: [Function],
  takeScreenshot: [Function],
  manage: [Function],
  navigate: [Function],
  switchTo: [Function],
  driver: 
   { session_: 
      { then: [Function: then],
        cancel: [Function: cancel],
        isPending: [Function: isPending] },
     executor_: { execute: [Function] },
     flow_: 
      { events_: {},
        timer: [Object],
        history_: [],
        activeFrame_: [Object],
        schedulingFrame_: [Object],
        eventLoopId_: [Object] } },
  element: { [Function] all: [Function] },
  '$': [Function],
  '$$': [Function],
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
  rootEl: 'body',
  ignoreSynchronization: false,
  params: {},
  moduleNames_: [],
  moduleScripts_: [] }
```